# How do I get Threads to work in ruby CGI

Tags: ruby, multithreading, cgi

I have the following script (ruby 1.9.3), if I comment out the two Thread lines it works fine, if I leave them in I get a 500 Internal error on my webserver.  Why does this not work in CGI, but work fine on the command line?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'cgi'

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"
TIMEOUT = 8

def worker(data, results)
        results[data] = rand(6)
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
        results = {}
        worker("abc", results)
        t = Thread.new{ worker("xyz", results) }
        t.join(TIMEOUT)
        print results
        print "done"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with looking at the error logs from your webserver with the hopes of seeing what is causing the 501.  I tried this on my server and it worked as expected.

Perhaps the webserver is starting up a different ruby or can't find the gems.

If you can't see it in the error logs, you could try catching errors with rescue, i.e.:

```
begin
    t = Thread.new{ worker("xyz", results) }
    t.join(TIMEOUT)
rescue => e
    puts e.inspect
end
```